# Why sagen, erklären, erzählen are dative verbs? why Lieben is not a dative verb?

Tags: grammatical-case, standard-german

I understand that sagen, erklären, erzählen are dative verbs but what's the logic behind treating them dative. Why lieben is not dative?

Comment: Having learnt German as foreign language, I'd advise just not to lose time with trying to find explanations to why each verb is governed by which case. (The worse was to try to find explanations to genders, for which rules exist only for very small class.) Memorization is the best you can do.

Comment: This question might be interesting for you: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/75997/what-are-cases-used-for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*sagen*, *erklären* and *erzählen* are transitive verbs and thus take an accusative object. It is just not the receiver of the said/explained/told thing.

The receiver is denoted as a dative object, and is optional. The accusative is required and a sentence would be incomplete without it.

It is the same as in English:

> Ich erkläre dich = I explain you = I explain what/who you are (sounds strange)
> Ich erkläre XXX = I explain XXX = I explain what XXX is (not mentioning to whom)
> Ich erkläre dir XXX = I explain XXX **to** you = I tell you what XXX is
> Ich erkläre dir = I explain to you (missing "what" object, may be implied)

*Lieben* on the other hand is also transitive, but cannot take a receiver as dative object. The loved thing is the accusative object

> Ich liebe dich = I love you
> <s>Ich liebe dir</s> = <s>I love to you</s>

Comment: Actually "Ich liebe dir" is not unheard of, just watch the afternoon program on RTL-II (as Alfred Dorfer once observed): "Komm zurück zu misch, isch liebe dir!"

Comment: "Ich erzähle euch von meinem Leben Leben" does not have an accusative object.

Comment: There's an implied accusative object "etwas".

Answer (score 5):

One (actually, one of the main, and actually its literal) purposes of the dative is denoting "giving something to someone". The notion of "giving" is interpreted very widely in languages that have a live dative to "do something for someone", and even "give a word to someone" and "give help to someone". That roughly explains why *sagen*, *erklären* *helfen*, and *erzählen* require the dative (as an optional object in addition to their mandatory accusative object).

The interpretation of "giving" does not so much extend to "lieben", so it forces the accusative. With respect to your "why is that" question, the answer is, as always in language questions, bluntly "because people talk that way". And, no, you should rather not expect or apply too much logic to a language.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that sagen, erklären, erzählen are dative verbs

*But they **aren't!***

Check out these examples:

> Er sagt **etwas.** ← That's an accusative object.
>
> Sie erklärt **den Ablauf.** ← Clearly an accusative object.
>
> Er erzählt **großen Mist.** ← Also, cleary an accusative object.

So those are just normal transitive verbs which feature an accusative object. But you *may* add a dative object to mark the **receiver** of the message:

> Er sagt **mir** etwas.
>
> Sie erklärt **mir** den Ablauf.
>
> Er erzählt **mir** großen Mist.

So the dative object tells who receives the accusative object, or more in general, **who bears the result of the action on the accusative object.**

---

With *lieben* you could indeed argue that the one loved is who *receives* the love. Similar as with *helfen* for example.

*Unfortunately, German isn't that regular.*

You have to remember for each verb which objects it takes. So it's

- jemande**m** helfen

but

- jemande**n** lieben

There's no way around drilling that, sorry.